# Accessing past USDA NRCS data

Tags: data, united-states

I am constructing a panel that includes past crop yields, but I found that SDA/WSS/GDG only grant access to the current version(2019) of cross-sectional tabular data.

Is it possible to access previous versions (dates)?

Comment: You have two tags that have no relevance to the question body. More detail in the question might make those tags relevant, or might suggest additional tags.

Comment: Could you please provide any relevant links to data?

Comment: If this question is about the availability of open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.